# How to Fetch values with tags to any built-in function in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template name="SampleState">
            <Param xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns="http://www.sample.con/ca/sse/sample-v3_0_0"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sample.con/ca/sse/sample-v3_0_0">
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of
        select="concat('sample-',normalize-space(/*/*/*[local-name()='state']/message/id))" />
                </name>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="normalize-space(/*/*/*[local-name()='state']/message/value)" />
                </value>
            </Param>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="request">
                <xsl:call-template name="SampleState"></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="mdfn:md5Hex($request)"/>
        </xsl:template>
```

Values for name and value are taken from soap request.I want to pass whole tags with values to any function.when i try using xsl:value-of with output-escaping="yes", it gives  only values but i need all tags.

Comment: what about using `xsl:copy-of`?

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use, how is the function `mdfn:md5Hex` defined, which parameter types does it expect, which is the return type?

Answer (score 0):

Below a short example to copy all elements, but not de "p", that becomes "para":

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">  
  <para>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </para>
</xsl:template>
```